# Python Script To Rename Bones In Armature

Tags: python, animation, scripting, rigging, armature

I was wondering if there was a python script that I could run in the text editor that would go through all the bones in a selected armature and remove the numbers from their name??

The bone names have to be the same if you want to append animations from other files, but this software I'm using always adds numbers to the bones depending on how many times you've exported a skeleton.

This skeleton contains a 31 before all the bone names. In other files it will be 45, or 129, so on so fourth. If I could run a simple script that would just remove all the numbers in each bone name, it would save me a lot of trouble from having to do it manually.

Thank you for your time!!!
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will replace "Skel123:", etc. with just "Skel:" in the names of bones (edit: and their armature, and their armature's object). Select the armature you want to do it to and make sure you are in Object mode before running it.

```py
import bpy, re
ob = bpy.context.active_object
assert ob.type == "ARMATURE"
assert bpy.context.mode == 'OBJECT'
for thing in [ob, ob.data, *ob.data.bones]:
    thing.name = re.sub(r'Skel[0-9]+:', 'Skel:', thing.name)
```

If you want to remove *all* numbers instead of just the ones from the "Skel:" part, you can use `re.sub(r'[0-9]', '', thing.name)` instead.

Comment: BRO!!! You're the man-! 
Goodness gracious, I wasn't expecting this much awesome. The code is beautiful, and works perfectly :)

If you don't mind me asking one last thing, what addition to the code would I need to make if I also want it to remove numbers from the name of the armature itself?

The bone names were all fixed, but the armature itself was still named "Skel31:Refernce". If possible, I'd like it to just be "Skel:Reference" -

If that's too much to ask, I understand, thank you for providing what you have :)

Comment: Glad it worked for you :) I've updated it to change the armature/object name too.

Comment: Thank you! It's perfect :)